# How to call function "Move" in C++ Builder 6

Tags: c++builder

Delphi syntax:

```
procedure Move(const Source; var Dest; Count: Integer);
```

C++ syntax:

```
extern PACKAGE void __fastcall Move(const void *Source, void *Dest, int Count);
```

I have used Function `Move` in Delphi long time ago,

recently I want to call it in C++ Builder 6,

I wrote it as the same as I did in Delphi,

the error appearance --> "Expression Syntax".

Dose anyone know how to call it?

or there is other function works similar to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
BYTE src[] = "Source Data";
BYTE dst[11];
Move(src, dst, sizeof(dst));
```

It is better to use **memmove** in C++:

```
memmove(dst, src, sizeof(dst));
```

Comment: It turns out that Move and memmove all functionally work in my program, it was something else went wrong in my code (I solved). But I am curious about the difference between these two functions, would you explain?

Comment: The first function is the member of delphi (pascal) runtime library and the second function is the member of c++ standard library. you can use both in your code and they do not differ in terms of performance. It is recommended to use std c++ functions to have portable code (Compilable in GCC or VC++ , ...) .